# nginx selectively proxy master node

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I (will) have a set of nginx servers (ubuntu 18.04) providing the same services (multiple vhosts). To keep them in sync I plan on replicating the config across them, however I have a couple of functions which need to be handled by a designated node: certbot renewals and log analysis reports. Lets call the designated node the "master" for want to a better term.

How can I best deal with these?

I could place the differences between the master and others in a snippets file outside the replication root, however this is a bit of a pig to maintain.

Can I use [conditional statements](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) (if...) within the location blocks, something like....

```
alias /var/www/letsencrypt/well-known;
location /well-known/
{ 
   if ( $somevalue != $master ) {
     proxy_pass https://master.example.local/well-known/;
   }
   if ( $somevalue = $master ) {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

Can I access the machines hostname from within nginx config? Is there something else I should use for $somevalue?

Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any suggestions, I have configured a new virtual host and proxy all requests to a hostname which only resolves to the master node.